# How to set the environment of a SDK in a script file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, embedded-linux

Some operations related to embedded Linux (e.g. Kernel build etc) requires the use of toolchain, thus the first command is:

```
$ source /opt/fslc-x11/2.2.1/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
```

I'd like to place this command inside a .sh script for Ubuntu: what's the right way?

Comment: Open the sh in an editor and add the line.  Or what is the question?

Comment: "source" in a bash script file has not the same meaning of source to set a development environment

Comment: If you call a script (execute it), it cannot affect your current running environment, as it creates its own shell to run into.  The only way to do this is to source the script in which you source the other file.